# project design problem

Tags: xml, database-design, treeview

In my web applications i have to generate seven different type of forms. There is a big 7 level tree and from that each first level subnode is a separate form. So for this what i am thinking is to generate 7 different xml files and to display the form like below given image i will parse the particular xml and display it. In my xml there will be node id and for each user i will store his selected nodes in the table so that i can retrieve later in my account section.

My question now are: is this xml approach proper...? and what kind of xml should i generated so that maximum flexibility can be kept in xml.. eg if i keep attribute validation: required in any node than it becomes required field in the generated html. i have to make a parser for that.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer this question is needed to know what technologies are you using in you proyect.

For example: In a java web project I should use JSON as it can be requested from javascript to update de form selections (jQuery+AJAX) an generated in server side from any data type you have stored it. It is very easy to do it with Spring.